# Selenium doesnt see my test suite

Tags: macos, selenium-ide

I've created a test suite in selenium IDE using the example code from the website and when I right click and attempt to load the suite it tells me the test is empty.  This is on latest stable ff for mac and selenium 1.07

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the open Test suite is under the menubar and the menubar title says firefox so I was confused.  Had only used selenium on linux before.  Found the openTestSuite and it worked like a charm now